# How to replace a chunk of symbols with one symbol in sympy

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

Given the following expression in `sympy`,

```
E = (x+y)/(a*b**2 +2*a) + x*y/(b**2+2)
```

how can I replace

```
1/(b**2+2)
```

with `c`, so that I get the following expression?

```
E = (x+y)*c/a + x*y*c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collect` method to collect for `a`, then proceed with the substitution:

```py
from sympy import *
var("a, b, c, x, y")
E = (x+y)/(a*b**2 +2*a) + x*y/(b**2+2)
E.collect(a).subs(1 / (b**2+2), c)
# out: c*x*y + c*(x + y)/a
```